# Pyqt6 draw double and triple bonds around an atom

Tags: python, pyqt, drawing, trigonometry, qpainter

I'm trying to draw possible bonds around a selected atom.
I am using cos and sin to find the positions of the possible new atoms in steps of 45° so I get 8 different positions , which works fine. When it comes to actually drawing the double or triple bonds, the bonds at 135° (top left) and 315° (bottom right) are shown as  single bond lines, instead of double or triple.

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Does anyone have an idea why this bug might occur or how to solve it?

This is a part of my paintEvent function:

```
# Calculate possible positions for new atoms in 360° around the selected atom
if self.selected_atom is not None:
    potential_positions = self.calc_potential_positions(self.selected_atom)
    for pos in potential_positions:
        # If atoms at position don't overlap, draw the potential bonds and atoms in different colour
        if not self.check_atom_overlap(pos[0], pos[1]):
            if self.bond_order == 2:
                self.draw_double_bond(self.selected_atom.x_coords, self.selected_atom.y_coords, pos[0],
                                      pos[1], False)
            elif self.bond_order == 3:
                self.draw_triple_bond(self.selected_atom.x_coords, self.selected_atom.y_coords,
                                      pos[0], pos[1], False)
            else:
                self.draw_single_bond(self.selected_atom.x_coords, self.selected_atom.y_coords,
                                      pos[0], pos[1], False)
            self.draw_atom_circle(pos[0], pos[1], self.selected_atom.x_coords,
                                  self.selected_atom.y_coords)
            self.draw_atom(pos[0], pos[1], self.element.SYMBOL, True)
            self.draw_center_atom(self.selected_atom.x_coords, self.selected_atom.y_coords,
                                  self.selected_atom.symbol)
```

```
@staticmethod
def calc_potential_positions(atom: chem_editor_logic.Atom) -> list[tuple[int, int]]:
    """

    :param atom:
    :return: list of tuples containing x and y coordinates of potential positions for new atoms
    """

    x = atom.x_coords
    y = atom.y_coords
    distance = 40

    # Calculate coordinates for angles in steps of 45 degrees from 0 to 360
    coordinates_list = []
    for angle_degrees in range(0, 360, 45):
        angle_radians = math.radians(angle_degrees)
        new_x = x + distance * math.cos(angle_radians)
        new_y = y + distance * math.sin(angle_radians)
        coordinates_list.append((int(new_x), int(new_y)))

    print(x, y)
    print(coordinates_list)
    return coordinates_list

def draw_single_bond(self, atom1_x: int, atom1_y: int, atom2_x: int, atom2_y: int, actual_bond: bool) -> None:
    painter = QPainter(self)
    pen = QPen()

    # Set colour black
    pen.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))
    pen.setWidth(2)

    if not actual_bond:
        # Set colour red
        pen.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
    painter.setPen(pen)

    painter.drawLine(QPoint(atom1_x, atom1_y), QPoint(atom2_x, atom2_y))

def draw_double_bond(self, atom1_x: int, atom1_y: int, atom2_x: int, atom2_y: int, actual_bond: bool) -> None:
    painter = QPainter(self)
    pen = QPen()

    # Set colour black
    pen.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))
    pen.setWidth(2)

    if not actual_bond:
        # Set colour red
        pen.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
    painter.setPen(pen)

    # Draw two lines for a double bond
    offset = 3
    painter.drawLine(QPoint(atom1_x - offset, atom1_y - offset),
                     QPoint(atom2_x - offset, atom2_y - offset))
    painter.drawLine(QPoint(atom1_x + offset, atom1_y + offset),
                     QPoint(atom2_x + offset, atom2_y + offset))

def draw_triple_bond(self, atom1_x: int, atom1_y: int, atom2_x: int, atom2_y: int, actual_bond: bool) -> None:
    painter = QPainter(self)
    pen = QPen()

    # Set colour black
    pen.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))
    pen.setWidth(2)

    if not actual_bond:
        # Set colour red
        pen.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
    painter.setPen(pen)

    # Draw three lines for a triple bond
    offset = 4
    painter.drawLine(QPoint(atom1_x, atom1_y),
                     QPoint(atom2_x, atom2_y))
    painter.drawLine(QPoint(atom1_x - offset, atom1_y - offset),
                     QPoint(atom2_x - offset, atom2_y - offset))
    painter.drawLine(QPoint(atom1_x + offset, atom1_y + offset),
                     QPoint(atom2_x + offset, atom2_y + offset))
```

Those are the functions in use here.

Comment: Ιf the line between your atoms is at 45 degrees to the x axis, then the points `(atom1_x - offset, atom1_y - offset), (atom2_x - offset, atom2_y - offset)` and so on fall exactly on that line. So the two parts of the double bond (and three parts of the triple bond) will fall exactly on top of each other.

Comment: My fault, I forgot to add something to the description of the problem earlier. I just updated the post and added a screenshot of the output and changed the text explaining it. The problem only occurs for the top left and bottom right bonds.

Comment: Right, that's exactly what you would expect for this problem. Can you see how for those bonds, transforming `(x, y)` to `(x+offset, y+offset)` displaces the point to another point which is exactly on the line of the bond?

Comment: I apologise for my extremely stupid mistake. I just remembered that the origin (0, 0) is the top left corner of my canvas and y increases down the canvas. In my brain it was always just (0, 0) in the bottom left corner with y increasing up. I just adjusted my offsets and now it works fine. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: No problem - it's easy to get confused with the different conventions between computer graphics and maths!

Comment: @Tom Note that it would be better to create just *one* unique instance of QPainter and eventually use it as argument of drawing functions; while there's technically nothing wrong in creating multiple painters (as long as you're completely sure that you're always using *one* active painter), it's a bit pointless to continuously create new ones for every function call, especially since you're using a for loop and each one of those functions initializes the painter in the same way, resulting in a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: @Tom Also consider that for such defined structures and complex drawing, using pure QPainter functions may become incrementally difficult, hard to maintain and quite cumbersome, especially if you plan to add further features to the program. I suggest you to have a look at the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html), which could seem a bit overwhelming at first, but it would eventually make achieving such drawings much simpler, since you'll be dealing with elements (items) instead of painting primitives.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your feedback. I am new to pyqt, so I am still figuring out how things work. I'll have a look at the Graphics View Framework!